# Is there a way to use a variable to comment out a line in the where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a line in my WHERE clause that would be a nice added feature to be able to toggle. This way the end user doesn't have to run two reports. I haven't found anything like it so I'm thinking you cannot but maybe I am looking at the problem the wrong way and someone else knows a better way.

I have tried to run the code below with the last line as `@AND` and defining the variable as `'AND' & '--'`giving me incorrect syntax error x2.
I also tried `IS @NULL` and defining the variable as `'NULL' & 'NOT NULL'` giving me incorrect syntax error x2

```
SELECT 
item_id
FROM 
cba_item_location
WHERE
discontinued='Y'
AND qty_on_hand = '0'
AND (select abc_code from abc_miscdata where abc_code=item_id and abc_type='ITEM' and data_1 ='DISCON_ZERO_SENT') IS NULL

order by item_id
```

Example 1:

```
SELECT 
item_id
FROM 
cba_item_location
WHERE
discontinued='Y'
AND qty_on_hand = '0'
**@AND** (select abc_code from abc_miscdata where abc_code=item_id and abc_type='ITEM' and data_1 ='DISCON_ZERO_SENT') IS NULL
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT 
item_id
FROM 
cba_item_location
WHERE
discontinued='Y'
AND qty_on_hand = '0'
AND (select abc_code from abc_miscdata where abc_code=item_id and abc_type='ITEM' and data_1 ='DISCON_ZERO_SENT') IS **@NULL**
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps an OR where your newly added condition will be toggled by the user like `AND (select abc_code from abc_miscdata where abc_code=item_id and abc_type='ITEM' and data_1 ='DISCON_ZERO_SENT') IS NULL OR @userSwitch = 1` That way if they don't care about that condition they set the `@userSwitch` to 1 and it just doesn't care if the other condition is true or false. (not sure what is possible from your "Reporting" front end though

Comment: You should post this as the answer Nevill, although be sure to be explicit with order of operations using the OR statement.

Comment: I think I understand it but cannot get it to work yet. Another fire popped up... Thank you for your help, I'll try some more tomorrow.

Comment: Perhaps Erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) would be helpful - and maybe a little daunting. You do mention "report" but you do not provide context for how "end user" runs a report. Without that, suggestions might be missing easier solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: dynamic SQL

Option 2: include a flag into your WHERE clause which will switch it on and off

```
DECLARE @and bit = 0
IF (some condition) SET @and = 1  
...
WHERE
discontinued='Y'
AND qty_on_hand = '0'
AND (@and = 1  AND (select abc_code from abc_miscdata where abc_code=item_id and abc_type='ITEM' and data_1 ='DISCON_ZERO_SENT') IS NULL)
```

Comment: This almost works but it's all or nothing. What I need is it to return the values for the query like the line wasn't there if it's 'False' and like it was if it's 'True'.